# how to dynamically check number of arguments of a function in php

Tags: php

how can I check at runtime home many parameters a method or a function have in PHP.

example

```
class foo {
   function bar ( arg1, arg2 ){
    .....
   }
}
```

I will need to know if there is a way to run something like

```
get_func_arg_number ( "foo", "bar" )
```

and the result to be

```
2
```

Answer (score 30):

You need to use [reflection](http://php.net/oop5.reflection) to do that.

```
$method = new ReflectionMethod('foo', 'bar');
$num = $method->getNumberOfParameters();
```

Comment: also see [`getNumberOfRequiredParameters()`](http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionfunctionabstract.getnumberofrequiredparameters.php)

Answer (score 9):

*Reflection* is what you're after here

```
class foo {
   function bar ( $arg1, $arg2 ){

   }
}
$ReflectionFoo = new ReflectionClass('foo');
echo $ReflectionFoo->getMethod('bar')->getNumberOfParameters();
```

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for the reflection capabilities in PHP5 -- documentation [here](http://php.net/oop5.reflection).

Specifically, look at the ReflectionFunction and ReflcetionMethod classes.

Answer (score -5):

I believe you are looking for func_num_args()

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.func-num-args.php

Comment: No. This is for use inside functions, and says how many arguments were passed to the function you are in.

Comment: That will return the number of arguments passed to the function when you've called it. The OP is looking for the number of arguments in the function signature, which may be different.