# Is there a way to figure out how many parameters a defined method expects from outside of the method? (PHP)

Tags: php, methods, parameters

I am working on creating an MVC framework, which passes any url parameters after the "action" parameter to the requested action via the action's method parameters.

so if the url is:

```
host/controller_name/action_name/param1/param2
```

the following takes place (simplified of course):

```
$requested_controller = new controller_name();
call_user_func_array(array($requested_controller, action_name), array(param1, param2);
```

The problem is in error reporting. If an url is requested with the wrong number of parameters (action expects two parameters, but url only contains one parameter, i get a warning message, then havoc).

Since this is a procedural error instead of an exception, I cannot try/catch it in any way, can I? Is there a way to check the number of expected parameters for the action method before trying to run it? Or should I be attacking this in an entirely different way?

EDIT (SOLUTION)

```
                $action_method_relfection = new ReflectionMethod($requested_controller, $requested_action);
                if (count($path_variables) < $action_method_relfection->getNumberOfRequiredParameters() || count($path_variables) > $action_method_relfection->getNumberOfParameters()) {
                    // if not, redirect to 404 error
                    self::redirect_to_404();
                }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to dynamically check number of arguments of a function in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/346777/how-to-dynamically-check-number-of-arguments-of-a-function-in-php)

Comment: only percieved issue with the final solution may be that developers get no warning if they have not included the right number of parameters in an url. will find a way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suppose that, using the [**Reflection API**](https://www.php.net/reflection), you could find out how many parameters each method accepts, using some combination of

- [`ReflectionClass::getMethod`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getmethod.php)
- [`ReflectionFunctionAbstract::getNumberOfParameters`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionfunctionabstract.getnumberofparameters.php)

Another solution would be to have your methods accepts just one -- and always one -- parameter : an array, that could contain any possible number of items.

This way, you always pass one parameter, all methods always expect one parameter ; and no warning / error anymore.

Comment: these are interesting ideas. the second one makes me nervous, as all parameters would be passed around via a numerical index of an array instead of a named parameter. the ambiguity would make the contained code confusing. I am going to research the possibilities of the first idea.

Comment: @dqhendricks You are not limited to numerical indices, you can also use strings as keys.

Comment: @jeroen where would I get these strings? they are not found in the url. i am not going to build key namers into every controller method.

Comment: solved my issue. thank you. see original post edit for final solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try something simple like

```
if (!isset($param1) || !isset($param2)) exit;
```

Comment: There may be hundreds of controllers classes with hundreds of action methods. I cannot make a check like this for each one.

Answer (score 0):

Although you can use the [`func_get_args()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php) function, it kind of feels the wrong way to go about it.

I would always make sure what function I´m calling and what (optional...) arguments it needs.

Comment: this function only works from inside the method, after the warning will have already occured.

Comment: @dqhendricks Only if there are not enough parameters and you can solve that using 1. default values or 2. not having any parameters defined in your function at all.

Comment: a requirement of needing to use default values for any public controller method seems cumbersome, and then requires checks within each method to make sure to gracefully handle invalid requests. - also, not having parameters defined would also cause confusion for anyone reading the contained code. - i do not want to put cumbersome requirements on the contents of every controller method.

Comment: @dqhendricks I agree, that's why I said it feels kind of wrong :-)