# How to dynamically call PHP method and pass multiple variables not in an array?

Tags: php, arrays, reflection

I want to be able to call a php function, but only if the number of elements input, matches the number of elements accepted by the function and if it does match i want to pass them 1 by 1 and not as an array.

Currently i have the following code which does the job, but is messy.

```
call_user_func($functionname, $vars);
```

This was hitting problems when i had a function that expected an array of 4 elements, but was only passed 3. Having to check and make sure all the vars exist makes writing functions a bit messy. I have a better solution based on reflection. [how to dynamically check number of arguments of a function in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/346777/how-to-dynamically-check-number-of-arguments-of-a-function-in-php) , but im one final step short. If the number of arguments matches the number of arguments in a function, i can call that method, but i dont know how to call that method correctly. I have an array of variables. I need to pass these into the function so that I can do something like the following.

```
function foo($var1, $var2, $var3)
{
    //I know all 3 vars exist and dont need to verify first
}
if(count($arrayof3elements) == get_method_var_count("foo") {
    dynamically_call_method("foo", $arrayof3elements);
}
```

Comment: [`call_user_func_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php) accepts an array as a 2nd argument but passes them in to the function as separate parameters (as you want).

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `call_user_func`, use `call_user_func_array` - this allows you to pass an array of arguments, but passes them to the method as separate things.

```
function x($foo, $bar) {
    echo $foo . $bar;
}

call_user_func_array('x', ['abc', 'def']); // prints abcdef
```